# Facebook Javascript Prompt Publish After Install

Tags: facebook, stream, publish

I am using Facebook connect and was wondering how I could prompt for a stream publish after app installation. Not every time you login. Here is my code on the login, I don't know how I could detect if the user just installed the app as opposed to is just logging in through this. Then what should I use for the publish prompt? Thanks

```
    FB.login(function(response) 
    {
       if (response.authResponse) 
       {
          var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
       }
    },{scope:'email,publish_stream'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your code to FB.getLoginStatus in first if block. Or you can subscribe to auth.login
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: That's actually what I have it as right now. The problem is that it calls that every time you try to log in. I only want to call it after the first time, after you accept permissions. I understand you can do this in the back end by just checking if it is the first time you are in the app or not, but since I am trying to do a prompt, it would be much easier if there is some way to check through the JS. Thanks

Comment: May be check/set cookie? But I think you should do it server-side: check if user login and first time install, and then publish "welcome" prompt. You could write code in PHP + Ajax, but I can't help with it.

Comment: Ya that's what I had to end up doing, I was just hoping there would be a simple check I could add in the JS login function. Thanks